# Erase the space between my div and the browser window

Tags: html, css

[space between my browser and my div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxGDv.png)

Hi guys, I'm a new dev and I would like to know how to erase the space between my div and my browser

Thanks

I try right=0; I try right=-10px; I try clear=both, but I'm not sure for this one.

Comment: You're going to need to post a [mcve] in your question. We can't debug images

Comment: impossible to know. Show code that produces the issue. Could be margins, padding, whitespace etc. Hard to guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset your browser's default styles by setting:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking at padding in CSS.

padding: 0px

to the div element in your CSS Stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the margin and padding to '0', as well as setting the box-sizing to 'border-box' on the root element (*) or body element in css. This may help

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I can provide more help if you post your code along with the question. Hope this helps